# How to solve this: Conversion from type DBNull to type string is not valid

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

1. I think this is were I think the error is showing when I close the crystal report after creating a report.

   ```
   Private Sub Populate(id As Integer, perdate As Date, controlnum As String, establishmentname As String, fname As String, mname As String, lname As String, address As String, pertype As String, ornum As String, amntpd As String, datepd As Date)

   Dim row As String() = New String() {id, perdate, controlnum, establishmentname, fname, mname, lname, address, pertype, ornum, amntpd, datepd}

   DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)

   End Sub
   ```

This is where the code for retrieving data from my database(MySql database) to datagrid view

```
    Private Sub retrieve()
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM tblfsesmis"


    Try
        Using con
            con.Open()
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
            adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)

            adapter.Fill(dt)

            For Each row In dt.Rows
                'It's in your Populate function that you want to check the DBNull values
                Populate(row(0), row(1), row(2), row(3), row(4), row(5), row(6), row(7), row(8), row(9), row(10), row(11))
            Next

            dt.Rows.Clear()
            DataGridView1.Refresh()
        End Using 'con Object will be disposed automatically
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Can you help me in how to solve this? please ! thank you

Comment: why don't you just set the data table as the datagridview's datasource? DatagridView1.DataSource = dt and remove the call to dt.rows.clear

Comment: where will i put the 'DatagridView1.DataSource = dt'

Comment: I would just set the Data source like Noob mentions. Or another option is to select your columns and surround them with `ISNULL` and replace it with an empty string...

Comment: I've set it but it displays a blank data in the datagridview

Comment: Do you have `Option String` set to `On` or `Off`? Because if it si `Of` then `DataRow(index).ToString()` return empty string if value is `DbNull`. In the `Populate` method `vb.net` will implicitly call convert `DataRow(index)` to `String` by calling `ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

If your application doesn't support null values for a field then modify your query so that null values cant appear.

So instead of: `SELECT * FROM tblfsesmis`

Use `SELECT Id, PerDate, IsNull(ControlNum, '') .... FROM tblfsesmis`.

IsNull will replace null values with a default that you have chosen.

Alternatively you can fix this in code with something like

`Dim result = If(Convert.IsDBNull(val), "", val)` on each field which could be null.

However as pointed out in the comment you don't appear to need these values to be cast to strings anyway. So just assign the datatable directly to the datasource.

Comment: Incorrect parameter count  in the call  to native function 'IsNull'

Comment: Which database are you using. That should work for SqlServer. MySql and others use IfNull

Comment: MySql database sir

Comment: So does it work if you use `SELECT Id, PerDate, IfNull(ControlNum, '') .... FROM tblfsesmis`

Comment: sql = '"SELECT id, IsNull(perdate, ''), controlnum, establishmentname, fname, mname, lname, address, pertype, ornum, amntpd, IsNull(datepd, '')  FROM tblfsesmis"'

Comment: If you're using mysql you need to replace isnull with ifnull. I'm not sure which of your fields are nullable but you'll want this on any nullable column.

Comment: Ok it displayed but how to rename the column field in the sql ?

Comment: This is my sql and it pop ups an error when it loads the form
`sql = "SELECT id as ID, IfNull(perdate, '') as Permit Date , controlnum as Control Number, establishmentname as Establishment Name, fname as First Name, mname as Middle Name, lname as Last Name, address as Address, pertype as Permit Type, ornum as OR Number, amntpd as Amount Paid, IfNull(datepd, '') as Date Paid  FROM tblfsesmis" `

Answer (score 0):

```
    Private Sub retrieve()
sql = "SELECT * FROM tblfsesmis"


Try
    Using con
        con.Open()
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
        adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)

        adapter.Fill(dt)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    End Using 'con Object will be disposed automatically
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

End Sub

Comment: I've tried  putting  DataGridView1.DataSource = dt but it displays the same rows as the data in the database but it is blank. why?

Comment: What do you mean "it displays the same rows as the data in the database but it is blank."? Does it show data or not? Does your database contain data?

Comment: it displays now but in different column

Answer (score 0):

Use `DataRow.Field(Of T)` extension method.
With `DataRow.Field(Of String)(columnIndex)` if value is `DbNull` then `Nothing/null` will be returned.

```
Populate(row.Field(Of Integer)(0), row.Field(Of String)(1))
```

If column of type Integer can be a NULL too, then use `Nullable` with `GetValueOrDefault` method

```
Populate(row.Field(Of Integer?)(0).GetValueOrDefault(), row.Field(Of String)(1))
```

But as @F0r3v3r-A-N00b suggested - you can use `DataTable` as datasource for `DataGridView`.

```
Private Sub retrieve()
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM tblfsesmis"

    Try

        Using con As New MySqlConnection(yourConnectionString)
            con.Open()

            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
                Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim dt As New DataTable()
                adapter.Fill(dt)

                DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
            End Using

        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

In this way `DataGridView` will be updated automatically. Just check that `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true`(it is true by default)